# how can I use coordinates of path walked by multiple subjects

Tags: plot, graph, statistics

I have the coordinates of the path 60 mice walked in their cage (each mouse was alone in a different cage) over a week. I want to somehow show the "average" path of all of the mice but not sure how to do that. my first idea was to divide the cage into segments and create a heatmap of the average amount of visits in each segment, but that doesn't tell me how many times they left and came back to each segment. I tried plotting all 60 mice into the same graph but that graph was messy and unreadable. anyone has any suggestion on how to combine all the paths together without losing information?
btw the coordinates are only X and Y axes (width and length of the cage) no Z axis (height) if that matters at all

Comment: Try plotting all paths on the same plot, with each path being drawn with a light gray color, and try to enable transparency (this is sometimes called "alpha", I think) so that multiple paths that cross the same point make that point darker.